# Why View [layouts.main] not found

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

View [layouts.main] not found.

why is this even though the place is correct why can't it be read?

[picture_home.blade.php](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HZ3tf.png)

the Header :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>kontol</h1>
    <div class="konteng">
        @yield('container')
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

Your layouts or blade files should be in `resources/views` folder. Move your file from `resources/layouts/main.blade.php` to `resources/views/layouts/main.blade.php`.

Then I assume your homepage using `beranda.blade.php`, you can use the layout like this :

```
@extends('layouts.main')

@section('container')
    {{-- code here --}}
@endsection
```